# AngularJS Json list

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I want to show one json to list in my page with AngularJS.But that Json have sub object i try something but not working. I can showing text and id but it's not working lat and lon in posibiton name tag.I don't know how to show that data in my list

```js
var app = angular.module("VarnaApp",[]);

app.service("varnaService",function($http, $q)
{
 var deferred = $q.defer();
 $http.get('api/station.json').then(function(data)
 {
  deferred.resolve(data);
 });

 this.getStations = function ()
 {
  return deferred.promise;
 }

 })


.controller ("varnaCtrl",function($scope,varnaService)
{
 var promise = varnaService.getStations();
 promise.then(function(data)
 {
  $scope.stations = data.data;
 });
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>AccioCode AngularJS Tutorial</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mainContainer" data-ng-app="VarnaApp">
 <h1>Varna Stations</h1>
 <div data-ng-controller="varnaCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Id</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>loc</th>

    </tr>

   </thead>
<tbody>
 <tr data-ng-repeat="station in stations">
 <td>{{station.id}}</td>
 <td>{{station.text}}</td>
 <td>{{station.loc}}</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>

  </table>
  
 </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My Json Is

```
[   
    {
        "id": 2063,
        "text": "test",
        "position": {
            "lat": 43.357048,
            "lon": 27.9815636
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2563,
        "text": "test2",
        "position": {
            "lat": 43.3570175,
            "lon": 27.9816666
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2538,
        "text": "test3",
        "position": {
            "lat": 43.3092232,
            "lon": 27.97827
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what station.loc should be. If you want to display lat and lon just do it like that:

```
<tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="station in stations">
    <td>{{station.id}}</td>
    <td>{{station.text}}</td>
    <td>{{station.position.lat}}</td>
    <td>{{station.position.lon}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping that is fix my problem :) . I was forgot to chose position :)

Answer (score -1):

The JSON you have is a JSON **string**. You have to parse it to a JavaScript object first:

```
.controller ("varnaCtrl",function($scope,varnaService)
{
    var promise = varnaService.getStations();
    promise.then(function(data)
    {
        $scope.stations = JSON.parse(data.data);
    });
})
```

Comment: but the `$http` deaultResponseTransformer will already parse the response into a JSON object.?

Comment: Yes it's work like that @Michael . I dont need JSON.parse. It's working now i can showing text and id but i can't show to page loc

Comment: Good to know @Michael. I really didn't know Angular do it automatically. It's a common mistake to not parse the JSON when making ajax requests, that's why I mentioned JSON.parse. Thanks!